# How to import a maven project to already existing android project?

Tags: maven, android-studio

I have created a Maven Project which is further dependent on some external jars and maven projects. This maven project can be used as a service by my front end clients "Android Espresso Suite", "WebSite automation suite", and "IOS Automation Suite". Maven project is packaged as a jar and uploaded to artifact. Now when my android espresso project tries to implement the project the gradle build gets failed.

I have tried implmenting my project as external jar/as maven artifactory/as fat jar but none of this has helped. Can anyone please help me how to proceed ?

This is how my build.gradle looks like:

Whenever I implement my fat jar:

> implementation
>   files('/{project-location}/{ProjectName}-0.0.1-dependencies.jar')

I get exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already
>   recorded as class: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MapContext     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:518)
>     at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.ClassVsInterface.addKnownInterfaces(ClassVsInterface.java:47)
>     at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visit(InterfaceDesugaring.java:105)
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)   at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)    at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:553)
>     at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:431)
>     at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:373)
>     at
>   com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:862)

When I implementation files using:

> implementation files('/{project-location}/{ProjectName}-0.0.1.jar')

and add dependent jars of this project, I get exceptions like

> "Path already exists for gson/hadoop/httpclients etc"

I have added this library as module as well. Have converted the maven project to gradle using

> gradle init and gradle build

, but whenever I try to import new module as gradle project it says please select module.

Has anyone done this before ? Please help.